# Is there any way to flag a database level configuration change (like delayed durability) that results in invalidating synchronous AG behavior?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2019

We have a SQL AG in synchronous mode (automatic failover), and some of the dbs in the AG have delayed durability enabled (FORCED). Technically this means that there is no guarantee of the durability property for the transactions in this db on either the primary or the secondary.

We look after several SQL servers. Is there any way to create a alert to detect such a setting so that DBA can be notified about this and take corrective action (in this case to set delayed durability to NONE).

Answer (score 1):

You could check with an agent job or a Policy Based Management Policy, eg

```
Declare @condition_id int
EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_syspolicy_add_condition @name=N'dd', @description=N'', @facet=N'Database', @expression=N'<Operator>
  <TypeClass>Bool</TypeClass>
  <OpType>EQ</OpType>
  <Count>2</Count>
  <Attribute>
    <TypeClass>Numeric</TypeClass>
    <Name>DelayedDurability</Name>
  </Attribute>
  <Function>
    <TypeClass>Numeric</TypeClass>
    <FunctionType>Enum</FunctionType>
    <ReturnType>Numeric</ReturnType>
    <Count>2</Count>
    <Constant>
      <TypeClass>String</TypeClass>
      <ObjType>System.String</ObjType>
      <Value>Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.DelayedDurability</Value>
    </Constant>
    <Constant>
      <TypeClass>String</TypeClass>
      <ObjType>System.String</ObjType>
      <Value>Forced</Value>
    </Constant>
  </Function>
</Operator>', @is_name_condition=0, @obj_name=N'', @condition_id=@condition_id OUTPUT
Select @condition_id
```